# UTF8NoBom in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I need to generate a txt file in UTF8 without BOM.  I started with:

```
"Text" | Out-File .\File.txt
```

which gives me UTF-16 LE encoding.

I tried

```
"Text" | Out-File .\File.txt -Encoding utf8
```

which gives me UTF-8 with BOM.

How do I get it without BOM?

Comment: In short: In _Windows PowerShell_, creating BOM-less UTF-8 files requires _workarounds_ - either via `New-Item` or via direct use of .NET APIs (fortunately, [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now - consistently - _defaults_ to BOM-less UTF-8). See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Christopher.